# Allshare Cast on Samsung Galaxy S III

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

How can I use Allshare Cast feature on my Samsung Galaxy S III? I have a samsung LCD with internet, Do I still need allshare dongle to use this feature?

Answer (score 1):

If your Samsung LCD TV doesn't have DLNA certified software or its not a DLNA certified device, you'll need AllShare Dongle. Check your TV's manual.

If your TV is DLNA certified, look its menu to use it. DLNA was designed for simplicity. Its truly plug-n-play. To use it, first connect both devices with same Wi-Fi network. Make one device server and other one client. Done!

Comment: Sachin. My TV is DLNA certified but how can I use Allshare Cast feature on my Samsung Galaxy S III?

Comment: @Shahid Updated the answer..

Comment: Well it's not working. There is an option of Allshare Play which can be used for multimedia files to be played on my TV. But Allshare Cast is for mirroring my device on my TV. It's a new feature of Samsung Galaxy S3. How can it be used? Please help.